# How to get value from child jsonnode using java

Tags: java, jsonnode

I need to get codec value from jsonnode using java. The following is the jsonnode with parent and child nodes.

```
{  
   "DetectedProperties":{  
      "Bitrate":262610704,
      "FrameRate":"24/1",
      "FileSize":32827252,
      "Height":1080,
      "Width":1920,
      "DurationMillis":1.0,
      "codec":"prores"
   }
}
```

the the following code snipet doesn't return a value for codec. It always returns null.

```
JsonNode videoProperties = getCodecInfo(videoFile);
JsonNode videoInfo = videoProperties.get("DetectedProperties");
log.debug("codec: " + videoInfo.get("codec").toString()); // returns null
```

How to get the codec value from the above json using java?

Kindly provide your inputs.

Comment: try to make a model class of your json array and get the value of element using that model class

Comment: try `videoInfo.get("codec").asText()`

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela getting java.lang.NullPointerException while trying your code

Comment: which Jackson version are you using?

Comment: Your code works. I am getting "prores" as a result. Could you check the code in getCodecInfo() whether it returns the json tree properly or not?

Comment: @S.K. Its not working for me.. :(

Comment: Can you try to print "videoProperties" and post the result here? If it is not fetching the tree properly, you can post the code to create the json tree here.

Comment: log.debug("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB: " + videoProperties.get("DetectedProperties"));
Result:  BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB: {"Bitrate":262610704,"FrameRate":"24/1","FileSize":32827252,"Height":1080,"Width":1920,"DurationMillis":1.0,"codec":"prores"}

Comment: This seems right. what is the output of next statement: videoInfo.get("codec") ? also can you try using asText() instead of toString()?

Comment: both getting NullPointerException :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178329/discussion-between-s-k-and-sst).

Answer (score 1):

You can use json expression "/DetectedProperties/codec" for this.

```
  JsonParser parser = new JsonFactory().createParser(getCodecInfo().toString());
  parser.setCodec(new ObjectMapper());
  TreeNode tree = parser.readValueAsTree();
  System.out.println(tree.at("/DetectedProperties/codec"));
```

Comment: Its not returning anything.. :(

Comment: at() method returns JsonNode. You can use asText() method to extract string from the this node.